# Disable Scroll When Dragging in MUI Grid

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, drag-and-drop, react-beautiful-dnd

I'm currently writing an app where I have many columns in a MUI Grid, scrolling horizontally. It's a task planner app, and when I create a task, I want to be able to drag it between the different columns that are visible on the screen. I'm using [hello-pangea/dnd](https://github.com/hello-pangea/dnd) to control the drag and drop functionality of the tasks, and as mentioned earlier, Material UI for the [Grid](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-grid/) that stores the columns.

However, I don't like the fact that it scrolls while I'm dragging - the Grid automatically scrolls while I'm dragging tasks. I want to disable this.

I already tried dynamically setting the `overflow` CSS style of the Grid depending on whether or not I'm dragging - if dragging, set `overflow-x` to `hidden`, otherwise, keep it as `scroll`. I expected this to disable the ability to scroll in the Grid, because if I initialize the Grid to have `overflow-x: hidden`, then scrolling is disabled. But, as you can see below, this does not help. Even though the style changes from `overflow: scroll` to `overflow: hidden`, the Grid still scrolls while dragging:

[image: Changing overflow-x dynamically depending on dragging doesn't affect ability to scroll]

(yes the UI needs work, I'll get to it eventually)

I tested this on both Google Chrome as well as Safari. I also tried using a state variable and setting the `sx` of the Grid component as follows. This didn't work either. My code looks something like the following:

```js
const View = (props) => {
    const [currentOverflow, setCurrentOverflow] = useState("scroll");

    // ...definition of taskView, etc...

    // props.dragging is a boolean passed down from the parent element
    // that is true when an item is being dragged, otherwise false 
    useEffect(() => {
        setCurrentOverflow((props.dragging) ? "hidden" : "scroll");
    }, [props.dragging])

    return (
        <Grid
            id={taskViewGridId}
            className="taskview"
            sx={{
                overflow: currentOverflow
            }}
        >
            {taskView}
        </Grid>
    )
}
```

The way I was trying to set the overflow parameter using CSS as I showed in that GIF before this code snippet was similar to the above, except the callback in the `useEffect` looked like this:

```js
var gridElt = document.getElementById(taskViewGridId);

if (props.dragging) {
    gridElt.classList.remove("enable-scroll");
    gridElt.classList.add("disable-scroll");
} else {
    gridElt.classList.remove("disable-scroll");
    gridElt.classList.add("enable-scroll");
}
```

where the associated CSS classes were just

```css
.disable-scroll {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.enable-scroll {
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

Can someone please help me figure this out? How do I disable scrolling in the MUI Grid depending on whether or not something is being dragged?

Thank you.

Comment: Don't post code as image except that you want answer as image.

Comment: @vee i've added more code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this. The @hello-pangea/dnd library automatically scrolls the window while dragging. An option to disable this has now been added to the library in their latest release.